# SQL - 'Not a GROUP BY expression'

Tags: sql

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID, CELLPHONE, CUSTORDER.ORDERDATE, SHIPPER.SHIPPERNAME, CUSTORDER.ORDERID, TO_CHAR((UNITPRICE * ORDERQUANTITY),'$999.99') AS TOTAL_PRICE, COUNT(CUSTORDER.ORDERID) AS ORDERS
FROM CUSTOMER INNER JOIN CUSTORDER
ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = CUSTORDER.CUSTOMERID
INNER JOIN CUSTORDERLINE
ON CUSTORDER.ORDERID = CUSTORDERLINE.ORDERID
INNER JOIN SHIPMENT
ON CUSTORDERLINE.ORDERID = SHIPMENT.ORDERID
INNER JOIN SHIPPER
ON SHIPMENT.SHIPPERID = SHIPPER.SHIPPERID
WHERE (UNITPRICE * ORDERQUANTITY) < '$2000'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID, CELLPHONE, CUSTORDER.ORDERDATE, SHIPPER.SHIPPERNAME, CUSTORDER.ORDERID;
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 1):

Run this, you are missing the char(...) in your group by

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID, CELLPHONE, CUSTORDER.ORDERDATE, SHIPPER.SHIPPERNAME, CUSTORDER.ORDERID, TO_CHAR((UNITPRICE * ORDERQUANTITY),'$999.99') AS TOTAL_PRICE, COUNT(CUSTORDER.ORDERID) AS ORDERS
FROM CUSTOMER INNER JOIN CUSTORDER
ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID = CUSTORDER.CUSTOMERID
INNER JOIN CUSTORDERLINE
ON CUSTORDER.ORDERID = CUSTORDERLINE.ORDERID
INNER JOIN SHIPMENT
ON CUSTORDERLINE.ORDERID = SHIPMENT.ORDERID
INNER JOIN SHIPPER
ON SHIPMENT.SHIPPERID = SHIPPER.SHIPPERID
WHERE (UNITPRICE * ORDERQUANTITY) < '$2000'
GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUSTOMERID, CELLPHONE, CUSTORDER.ORDERDATE, SHIPPER.SHIPPERNAME,
CUSTORDER.ORDERID, TO_CHAR((UNITPRICE * ORDERQUANTITY),'$999.99');
```